# Finding a set of representatives that sum to zero.

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, algorithms, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $2n$, where $n$ is an odd integer (For simplicity, we may assume $G\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ (the cyclic group of order $2n$). Let $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ be a partition of the elements of $G$ to two-element subsets. I have the following claim:

There always exists set of representants $X=\{a_i \mid a_i\in A_i\}$ such that $\sum_{x\in X}x=0$ where $0$ is the identity element in $G$. $X$ should contain exactly $1$ element from each pair $A_i$.

My question is: How to prove the statement above and also is there an efficient way of finding the representants? (Say in polynomial time with respect to $n$)?

If the proof would involve too much advanced group theory, we may indeed assume that $G$ is the cyclic group of order $2n$ (but it still has to be interesting).

EDIT: $n$ has to be odd!

Comment: Does the set $X$ need to contain exactly one representant per class?

Comment: Yes, it has to really be a set of representatives for the partition. Clarified it in the question.

Comment: Why does n have to be odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I already figured it out, I will post the answer.

Fix $n$ odd and let $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ be the pairs given on the input. Let us work in $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$. Let $B_1,\ldots, B_n$ be defined as follows: $B_i = \{i-1,i-1+n\}$. In other words $B_1=\{0,n\}$,$B_2=\{1,n+1\}$,$B_3=\{2,n+2\},\ldots,B_n=\{n-1,2n-1\}$.

Let $\mathcal{A}=\{A_i \mid i \in [n]\}, \mathcal{B}=\{B_i\mid i \in [n]\}$.

Claim 1: For any set of representatives from $\mathcal{B}$ they sum to $0$ modulo $n$.

Proof: Consider picking $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)=(0,1,2,\ldots,n-1)$. Exchanging any $b_i\in B_i$ with $b_i'\in B_i\setminus \{b_i\}$ increases the sum by $n$. It is thus enough to show that $\sum_i b_i = 0$. Note that $x:=\sum_ib_i=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. Since $n$ is, by assumption odd, $n-1$ is even, thus $(n-1)/2$ is an integer, thus $x$ is a multiple of $n$, thus zero modulo $n$.

Consider the bipartite (multi)graph $G=(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B},E)$ where $\{A_i,B_j\}\in E$ if and only if $A_i\cap B_j\neq \emptyset$.

It is not hard to observe that $G$ is $2$-regular so by Hall's theorem it has a perfect matching $M$.

Well, in fact it may happen that $A_i=B_j$, so we should really add a multi-edge there, but any maximum matching will choose this only edge. To be ultrapedantic, $G$ is a disjoint union of a 2-regular and a 1-regular graph.

Observe that the matching chooses one element $x_i$ from each set $A_i$. We know that the choices in fact correspond to chosing representatives from $\mathcal{B}$ and these either sum up to $0$ mod $n$. In mod $2n$ they either sum up to $0$ or $n$. Fix the representatives $x_i\in A_i$. If these do sum to $0$ mod $2n$, we are done. Otherwise do the following:

Create a multigraph (loops allowed) $H=(\mathcal{A},E')$ where $\{A_i,A_j\}\in E'$ if and only if there is some $B_i=\{x,y\}\in\mathcal{B}$ with $x\in A_i$ and $y\in A_j$. I.e., two pairs are connected if they contain elements from some pair in $\mathcal{B}$.

Observe again that the graph is $2$-regular. In other words it is a disjoint union of cycles (we regard a single vertex with a loop as a cycle of length 1). Since it has $n$ vertices and $n$ is odd, one of the cycles need to be of odd length.

Let $A_{i_1},A_{i_2},\ldots,A_{i_k}$ be an odd cycle in $H$. Let $B_{j_1},B_{j_2},\ldots,B_{j_k}$ be matched to the $A_i$'s. That is $\{A_{i_\ell},B_{j_\ell}\}\in M$ for all $\ell\in[k]$.

If $k=1$, then this is simply a loop, so we can change the representative in $A_{i_1}=A_{i_k}$ since $A_{i_1}=B_{j_1}$ in that case.

Let $A_{i_\ell}=\{x_\ell,y_\ell\}$. And let $x_\ell$ be the chosen representatives from $A_{i_\ell}$.

Start with $B_{i_1}=\{z_1,z_1+n\}$. Since $\{A_{i_1},B_{i_1}\}\in E(G)$, we have $x_1=z_1$ (wlog). Then, without loss of generality (otherwise it is the neighbor $A_{i_k}$), the neighbor $A_{i_2}$ of $A_{i_1}$ contains $x_1+n$ (by definition of the edges in $E(H)$). Like this, we create a new matching $M'=M\setminus \{\{A_{i_1},B_{j_1}\},\ldots,\{A_{i_k},B_{j_k}\}\}\cup \{\{A_{i_1},B_{j_2}\},\{A_{i_2},B_{j_3}\},\ldots,\{A_{i_k},B_{j_1}\}\}$. This is indeed a correct matching of $G$ and the representants chosen in the $A_i$'s now sum to $0$ mod $2n$.

All this can be accomplished in $O(n\sqrt{n})$ time using bipartite matching and then running a simple bfs or dfs to find the odd cycle in $H$.

E: In fact, since the graph is 2-regular and bipartite, it is a collection of even cycles, in which the matching can be found even in linear time. Thus we can improve the running time to $O(n)$.